# Specify setuptools sdist source distribution to only create folder

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I know that in `setuptools`, if I want to specify the creation of a source distribution I would simply have to run:

```
setup.py sdist
```

Using the `formats` flag, I can specify the output distribution format (for example, zip and/or tar - see https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/sourcedist.html).

However, I was wondering if there's a way to create the source distribution *without* a format - ie, just leave them in the unzipped folder.

I could not find anything in the docs or anywhere obvious in the source code (https://github.com/pypa/setuptools).

Is this possible? Or, will I have to just unzip the output archive afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `--keep-temp` option:

```
  --keep-temp (-k)  keep the distribution tree around after creating archive
                    file(s)
```

Comment: Yep, that's close enough.